# Como inserir em um memo no lazarus o cabeçalho da NFe e/ou todos produtos de um xml?

Tags: xml, lazarus

Consigo inserir o xml de uma nfe com o código abaixo, mas gostaria de inserir apenas o comprador, ou só os produtos, ou só o fornecedor...

Código testado no lazarus no windows 10.

```
procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DOC:TXMLDocument;
  i, j: Integer;
  OrderChilds, properties_Node: TDOMNode;
  propChildList: TDOMNodeList;
begin
  ReadXMLFile(Doc, 'C:pastaXML\arquivo.xml');
memo2.Clear;
  for i := 0 to DOC.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
  begin
    OrderChilds := DOC.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[i];
    if OrderChilds.NodeName = 'NFe' then
    begin
      properties_Node := OrderChilds.ChildNodes[0];
      if Assigned(properties_Node) then begin
        propChildList := properties_Node.ChildNodes;
        for j := 0 to propChildList.Count - 1 do begin
          Memo2.Lines.Add(propChildList[j].TextContent);

        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Seja benvindo ao StackOverflow em português! Experimentou fazer a solução após a leitura dos dados?

Comment: Sim, acabei eu mesmo achando a solução. vou postar

Answer (score 0):

Analisando o código anterior com mais atenção eu mesmo consegui resolver. Lembrado que pra retornar o próximo dado do produto é só aumentar o número do GetChildNodes.Item[2].TextContent

```
var xDoc: TXMLDocument;
nodedet, nodeInfNfe : TDOMNode;
   i:integer;

begin
    memo3.Clear;
  ReadXMLFile(xDoc, 'c:\pastaDoNFe\nfe.xml');
  nodeInfNfe:=xdoc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0];
  for i:= 0 to nodeInfNfe.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
 begin
   if nodeInfNfe.ChildNodes[i].NodeName = 'det' then
   begin
        nodedet:= nodeInfNfe.ChildNodes[i];
        //retorna o primeiro item dos produtos campo cProd
        memo3.Lines.add(nodedet.FindNode('prod').GetChildNodes.Item[0].TextContent

        //retorna o segundo item dos produtos campo cEAN
        +'= '+ nodedet.FindNode('prod').GetChildNodes.Item[1].TextContent

                //retorna o terceiro item dos produtos campo xProd
        +'= '+ nodedet.FindNode('prod').GetChildNodes.Item[2].TextContent);
```